# Better way to create a Lambda expression validator in PHP

Tags: php, lambda, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to create a program that checks if the Lambda expression the user input is valid.

I'm currently using REGEX as my approach but my advisor says that using REGEX limits the capability of my program.

Is there any other way? Parsing maybe?

Comment: Use `eval`. I'm kidding, don't ever use `eval`. Can you provide some code please? It's easier that way.

Comment: Regular expressions can only validate something which follows a regular grammar. General lambda expressions do follow a regular grammar, unless you're defining the syntax (or plan to define the syntax) in such a way that you can't use a regular grammar to describe them.

Comment: @apokryfos so do u mean that I could just continue using regex? 
and what does it mean if i define the syntax? can you elaborate :D. sorry im kinda new at this

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. I thought the user was supposed to give you some input which would be a lambda expression (e.g. like the one defined in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Definition)) and you'd just validate that input which is basically a few regex rules.

Comment: yeah the user inputs a lambda expression and then the program does its job to check if it is valid by following the rules